# Github tells one user that there are conflicts, but not the other user

Tags: git, github

We have a repository on Github. One user has created a branch, checked it in to Github, and created a pull request. When he logs in to Github and looks at the PR, there is a message at the bottom that says that there are no conflicts and this PR can be merged. There is a green button to do it.

When I log into Github and look at the same PR, I see a different message: "This branch cannot be rebased due to conflicts. Rebasing the commits of this branch on top of the base branch cannot be performed automatically due to conflicts encountered while reapplying the individual commits from the head branch."

Why aren't we seeing the same thing?

Is there something different about our logins, some configuration option?

He may have different options in his IDE, but that shouldn't make a difference. There's only one version of the repo on Github. He's on Windows and I'm on Mac, but that shouldn't make a difference either.

Is there a way for me to see what the conflicts are, exactly, before I try to rebase locally?

Comment: Do you have the same dropdown option selected? You have rebase, but if you switch to merge, is there a conflict?

Comment: @Ry- Yes! That was it. Why would there be rebase conflicts but not merge conflicts? (I know I'm having some conceptual difficulties here.)

Comment: One example is if the PR has a merge commit where the parent from the PR would have had a rebase conflict. You can fix merge conflicts by merging back the other way (adding a commit), but there’s no way adding a commit on top of what already exists can make what already exists go on top of the target branch’s history cleanly if it didn’t before. That was kind of convoluted, but I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Rebase applies one commit at a time. If one commit tries to change a line of code which would be in conflict with the branch you're rebasing on, that will be a conflict. However, if a later commit would then undo that change, a merge would succeed without a conflict. A rebase takes each commit into account, one at a time, a merge only applies the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be rebase conflicts and no merge conflict if one revision is adding code that is a conflict generator and then another revision takes it back. If you merge, that branch **won't** have the conflicting code... but if you go revision by revision (as in a rebase), you will have to deal with the conflict twice.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments below the question, this is because GitHub is offering to *merge* the commits for the guy who sees no problem, but for you, GitHub is offering to *rebase* the commits.  Sometimes, merges are easy and rebases are not.

Here's a trivial example of a commit series that can be merged easily, but not rebased.  First, let's draw the actual graph of commits:

```
...--G--H------L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- branch
```

In commit `H`, file `makeconfict` reads as follows:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

In commit `L`, we change line 2 to read `This is line two`.  So `H`-vs-`L` changes line 2 of file `makeconflict` (and makes no other changes).

Meanwhile, in commit `I` we *delete* line 2 of file `makeconflict`.  In commit `J` we make a useful change in some useful file, without touching file `makeconflict`.  In commit `K`, we put line 2 of file `makeconflict` back.

If we attempt to `merge` commit `K` (tip of branch `branch`) into `master`, Git compares `H` vs `L` and sees that `makeconflict` has line 2 changed.  It compares `H` to `K`: this says we must, from `H`, change line 2 of file `makeconflict`, to retain the changes made in `master`.  Then it compares `H` to `K` to see what we did.  Since we put line 2 back in `K`, the only *change* Git needs to combine with the change to `makeconflict` is the change to the important file.  So the merge goes smoothly, changing the important file, and we get:

```
...--G--H------L--M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \       /
          I--J--K   <-- branch
```

If we attempt to *rebase*, however, Git needs to copy commit `I` to a new commit `I'` that comes after `L`:

```
                 I' [in progress, not actually committed yet]
                /
...--G--H------L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- branch
```

The attempt to copy `I` to `I'`—the difference from `H` to `I`—says that we must *delete* line 2 of file `makeconflict`, while the difference between `H` and `L` is that we must *change* line 2 of file `makeconflict`.  These two different changes conflict with each other.  We must choose which change to make: replace `2` with `two`, or delete the line entirely?

If we delete the line entirely—which requires manual intervention, and GitHub won't do that through the web UI–we can go on to copy `J` to `J'` and `K` to `K'`:

```
                 I'-J'-K'   <-- branch (HEAD)
                /
...--G--H------L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

In this process we've put line 2 of file `makeconflict` back to the way it was originally, and still is in the now-abandoned commit `K`.  So we get one merge conflict (copying `I` atop `L` to make `I'`) and, in effect, end up undoing the change made in `L`.  But once we're done we have a series of commits that merely add directly to `master`, so that we can advance the name `master` to commit `K'`, by using `git checkout master; git merge --ff-only branch`:

```
...--G--H------L--I'-J'-K'   <-- branch, master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

Or, of course, when handling the merge conflict at `I'` we can choose instead to discard our change from `I` and keep `L`'s change.  In the end, we just skip copying `I` entirely.  When we get to copying commit `K` to make `K'`, we will typically get another merge conflict, although sometimes Git will realize that there's no need for commit `K` either.  If we handle the conflict correctly, we'll drop `K` as well:

```
                 J'  <-- branch (HEAD)
                /
...--G--H------L   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
```

and again we can now fast-forward `master` to point to copy `J'`.

This particular example is of course rather artificial, but these things really do happen in real life.